# Feign Error using Spring Cloud to connect multiple ports to server

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

```
> feign.FeignException$ServiceUnavailable: [503] during [GET] to
> [http://currency-exchange/currency-exchange/from/USD/to/INR]
> [CurrencyExchangeProxy#retrieve(String,String)]: [Load balancer does
> not contain an instance for the service currency-exchange]    at
> feign.FeignException.serverErrorStatus(FeignException.java:265)
> ~[feign-core-12.4.jar:na]     at
> feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:206)
> ~[feign-core-12.4.jar:na]     at
> feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:194)
> ~[feign-core-12.4.jar:na]     at
> feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:104)
> ~[feign-core-12.4.jar:na]     at
> feign.ResponseHandler.decodeError(ResponseHandler.java:136)
> ~[feign-core-12.4.jar:na]     at
> feign.ResponseHandler.handleResponse(ResponseHandler.java:70)
> ~[feign-core-12.4.jar:na]     at
> feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:114)
> ~[feign-core-12.4.jar:na]     at
> feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:70)
> ~[feign-core-12.4.jar:na]     at
> feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:96)
> ~[feign-core-12.4.jar:na]     at
> jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy99.retrieve(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]  at
> com.in28minutes.microservices.currencyconversionservice.controller.CurrencyCoversionController.calculateFeignCurrencyConversion(CurrencyCoversionController.java:43)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
>   at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]   at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]    at
> jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:6.0]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]    at
> jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:6.0]  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
> ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]  at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Please look into issue and suggest me ways to clear it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.